# How to compare javascript string that contain numeric in format of XX.XX.XXXX.XXXX

Tags: javascript

I have 2 strings in javascript that contain numeric numbers which represent file version.

i.e

```
var str1 = "11.11.1111.1111"
var str2 = "11.22.3333.5555"
```

How can i perform numeric comparison between them? 
I would like to check if `str1 > str2`

Comment: do you mind if `10.0.0.0` sorts between `1.0.0.0` and `2.0.0.0`? If you don't just do `str1 > str2`

Comment: You must first also validate whether the strings are of required types and then perform comparison operations..

Answer (score 5):

As long as str1 and str2 are guaranteed to be the same length and format, just do `str1 > str2`. String comparison is lexicographical (compare the first character of both, the second character of both... and return the value of the first difference), and for two equal length numbers/number-like strings that gives you exactly what you want.

If they are not guaranteed to be the same, try [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ting by `.`, [converting each string part to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript) and comparing them int-wise one by one until you find a difference.

Comment: "try splitting by ., casting each part you get back to int and comparing them int-wise one by one until you find a difference" -- Is there a lib for that?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak It's a built-in function of Javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split   For casting string to int: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript

Comment: I mean, is there a library that already does all of "splitting by `.`, casting each part you get back to int and comparing them int-wise one by one until you find a difference" in one call?

Comment: @Jan Dvorak Why would one exist?

Comment: It's a common operation so I guess someone must have already implemented it into their library.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for:

```
var str1 = '11.11.1111.1111'
   ,str2 = '11.22.3333.5555'
   ,compare = str1.split('.')
               .map(function(a) {
                    return +a > +(this.splice(0,1));
                },
                str2.split('.'))
              .reduce(function(a,b){return a||b;});
 //=> compare now: false
```

Comment: Replaced the answer with another approach

Comment: I can't see how it should work. What is the intention behind the `reduce` step? You should only accound for the most major version that they differ in, not count every place where they differ. The same for the other argument. It seems to me that replacing the reduce step iterator with `function(a,b){return a||b}` would act as desired. Also what's the point of `+(+a)` as opposed to `+a`?

Comment: Also, why not use `unshift` instead of `splice`?

Comment: `unshift` is non destructive. `a||b` is better, yep. `+(+a)` is a slip of the keyboard so to speak.

Comment: `unshift` _is_ destructive. I meant [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift), however, which _is_ destructive too.